# How do I include a camera support package in a MATLAB compiled application?

Tags: matlab, camera

I'm trying to create a MATLAB compiled application that uses an Allied Vision GigE camera. My code works fine when running in MATLAB directly, but when I run the compiled standalone executable, the software produces the error:
**There are no devices installed for the specified ADAPTORNAME**
when I call

```
vid  = videoinput('gige', 1, 'mono');
```

How do I add the support package for the camera into the executable?

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your matlab or use imaqreset. After that you can run your .exe file. Because only one connection can be occured at the same time.